# Query the Loop without breaking it

Tags: categories, query

Im trying to make different querys in my category like one with a offset of post and one that shows one post but while it continues to go through the loop, this is what i have but the loop keeps repeating itself i almost think im not doing it correctly. Anyone know whats wrong?

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : $count = 0; ?>

                                <div id="featured-category">
                                <div class="heading"><h2 class="recent-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
                                <?php query_posts('showpost=1'); ?> 
                                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                <div class="FC-image">
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php endwhile ?>
                                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

                                <div id="recent-posts">
                                <!-- Post Starts -->
                                <div class="post">
                                <?php query_posts('showpost=4&offset=1'); ?> 
                                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>                 
                                <div class="post-img">                  
                                </div>
                                <div class="heading"><h2 class="recent-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
                                <div class="recent-post-content">
                                <?php get_the_excerpt_limit( 200, '...&nbsp;Read More&nbsp;&raquo;' ); ?>                   
                                </div><!-- /.heading -->                    
                                </div><!-- /.post -->
                                <?php endwhile ?>
                                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>


                                <?php query_posts('offset=4'); ?> 
                                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                <div class="post">
                                <div class="heading"><h2 class="recent-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
                                <div class="recent-post-content two">

                                <?php get_the_excerpt_limit( 200, '...&nbsp;Read More&nbsp;&raquo;' ); ?>                   

                                </div><!-- /.heading -->

                                </div><!-- /.post -->
                                <?php endwhile ?>
                                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>        
                                <?php endwhile ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a really inefficient way to do it.

Just use the $count variable you declared at the top, without any query_posts():

```
$count = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

if ( $count < 1 ) {
  // first post
} elseif ( $count <= 4 ) {
  // next 4 posts
} else {
  // rest of the posts
}

$count++;
endwhile;
```

Also, it's 'showposts' not 'showpost'. Or use the newer 'posts_per_page'.

Comment: well it partly works, but for some reason it doesn't show my second query, the one that has showposts im guessing its because of the elseif statement.

Comment: I don't think you understood. See updated answer.

Comment: i understand but the way its posted its shows up on my site as all one posted field this is how i applied your code to it http://pastebin.com/t5CiZaUZ

i appreciate you taking time out to help

Comment: Ah, logic fail. It's supposed to be `$count < 1`, not the other way around. Updated answer.